# PostgreSQL syntax error eof caused commit

Tags: postgresql, transactions

We are working on merging individual files into a group PostgreSQL database. The files have all been working perfectly fine on their own and when we have combined we have run them with no problems. It started to hang on the creation of one trigger, so we commented the trigger out. The next time we ran the merge file we got the following error:

```
ERROR: Syntax error at end of input
LINE 181: --$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Following this error there were subsequent syntax errors and then to our horror we found the following in our log file:

```
ERROR: Syntax error at end of input
LINE 181: --$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql 
COMMIT
```

We had tests in this file that contained test data that was NOT supposed to be entered into the database, corrupting who knows how much of the data in our database. We have looked through every file included and there is no `COMMIT` anywhere!

Has anyone ever run into something similar? Is there any reason why an error in parsing would ever cause a commit?

Comment: EXTENSION: What seems to have happened is that it got half way through a comment, interpreted something as the EOF, kept parsing, encountered an error and somehow interpreted the bytes as a commit. Does anyone know if there is ANY WAY possible to revert the database to a previous state? This is extremely detrimental and we have NO TIME to do a manual rebuild!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a `BEGIN` statement, then the PostgreSQL connection is in "autocommit" mode, committing each change after the statement is run. Since you're incorrectly commenting your code, I'd say you've commented the `BEGIN` statement earlier in the code. But I can't be sure because you did not provide any of your SQL.

Note that the syntax:

```
--$$
```

does not comment out the end of function `$$`. What it means is empty comment as the last thing inside a string. It might help you if you read the line as:

```
--
$$
```

That is why you're getting a parse error on a "commented" line. If it was actually commented, PostgreSQL would not parse it. `$$` is a quote operator enclosing SQL code, and is just a convenience syntax against using `'`'s for quoting (which would mean you have to double-quote each quote inside the quoted SQL). What you think was a commented out line was actually just a piece of a string ending with two hyphens.

On a general note: You should use commenting only for adding descriptions to the code and not disabling sections of code. Use version control if you need to have access to older versions of the code.

**Edit:** Clarified explanation on quoted strings. Hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: This makes great sense. This was for a university project that was due only a few hours after having posted this question. The professor that teaches this databases class doesn't go over any SQL (or in this case postgreSQL) and leaves that up to the TA. The only thing the TA does in is go briefly over some examples of building a basic table and performing different operations on those tables so these little nuances (comments not actually commenting out code, etc) were never explained to us and as you can see they caused great complications. Thank you very much, this clear things up greatly.